# Facebook/Twitter login in my application

Tags: asp.net, social-networking, user-tracking

I am developing my site and in my site I want users to login through their 
social network credentials like Facebook and Twitter.

How should I track these users whenever they do any event on my site? Suppose a user logs in with Facebook username & password, and now he is redirected to the next page. On that page, we are doing some activity like 'add something'. How to track this?

Is there any procedure for working with this?

Comment: so you have no idea how to create a users table on your own database and insert data to it, but you want step by step explanation for what you've asked. Smells like homework.

Answer (score 3):

The common practice is to associate user's Facebook or Twitter account with your internal account and then track all user activity via your internal account id. If the newly logged in user doesn't have an internal account, then silently create it from Facebook/Twitter data and auto-associate.

Btw, integrating your ASP.Net app with Facebook and Twitter will be easier using [Facebook C# SDK](http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/) for Facebook and [Twitterizer](http://www.twitterizer.net/) for Twitter.

Comment: thanks buru, i have all the userinfo of facebook and twitter user account,now where we associate the userinfo with internal database means when user click on the facebook or twitter button and then in code behind we insert the userinfo in our user table or redirect user to the register page and then fill the fields with the info we have and then register.

Comment: So, you're registering users in your database, filling their info from Twitter/Facebook account? If this is correct, then what's your problem?

Comment: yeah that's correct but i need some step by step process where to enter userinfo in database etc .

Comment: Isn't it obvious? 1) You get user info from Twitter or Facebook, e.g. first name, last name, username. 2) Check whether this external account is already associated with your internal account; if it is - log user in, else - 3) Create an account for this data in your database 3) Create an association between external and internal account in your database (your specific process may require user to fill in some additional fields, but it's always better to do this under the hood or after registration). 4) Log user in under an internal account using your method of choice, e.g. FormsAuthentication.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look a the OAuth C# Library
http://www.matlus.com/oauth-c-library/

Comment: yes i have seen these examples,but my question is after fetching user info from facebook,twitter,vimeo after that what is the procedure to handle that userinfo in my application means we have to register this user to our website or something else.