# Implementing logins from social external sites

Tags: asp.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Facebook/Twitter login in my application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5563313/facebook-twitter-login-in-my-application)

I want all the visitors of my web application have the option to login to my site using their Facebook account.

Many sites provide logging in via social sites like facebook,gmail,yahoo,linkedin etc.

How can I implement all those login systems with my asp.net web application?

Currently i am using my own database to store user id and password and using the method **FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage()** for login.

Comment: @dknaack I am a beginner level developer i checked your link but that not help me.If u have some solution that is from the beginning than please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Check out oAuth. Here is a nice tutorial

http://www.matlus.com/oauth-c-library/

hope this helps